How many $4$-digit integers $n$ are there with no repeated digit such that exactly two digits of $n$ are even?

How many $4$-digit integers $n$ are there with no repeated digit such that exactly two digits of $n$ are even?

The answer says

With zero: $\binom 41\binom52\times3\times3!$.
Without zero: $\binom42\binom524!$

This is the answer, I can not figure out the first line answer. Can anybody explain this?
Calculating these values can yield the total number of valid 4-digit integers under the given constraints. This approach systematically breaks down both scenarios and utilizes combinatorial counting and arrangements to find the final solution.

Did you try to solve this yourself?

Pl first type out the subtype of the question  where you are having difficulty with the formula, and what you think it should be.

'I can not figure out the first line answer' So may be you show how you approached it and what your results are? Also: be aware given answers are written by people, and people sometimes make mistakes. If you get a different result that the author gave, maybe – just may be – that answer is wrong and your is correct...?

Now we have 3 digits (the selected even digit, 0, and the two odd digits) to place in a 4-digit number. Since 0 cannot be in the leading position, we first choose one of the digits that is not 0 to be the leading digit. There are 3 options for the leading digit (from the even digit
{
2
,
4
,
6
,
8
}
{2,4,6,8} and the two odd digits).
After choosing the leading digit, we have 3 remaining digits to arrange, which can be done in
3
!
6
3!=6 way

Maybe you need to think about it a little longer.
$\\$
$\\$
$\\$
With zero:
$\\$
Select $ 2 $ digits  in  $\{1,3,5,7,9\} \Longrightarrow \binom{5}{2} $
$\\$
Select $ 1 $ digit  in  $\{2,4,6,8\} \Longrightarrow \binom{4}{1} $
$\\$
Select  a  digit  as  the  first  digit  of  the  number $ \Longrightarrow \binom{3}{1} = 3 $ (you can't  select $ 0 $)
$\\$
Make a full permutation of the remaining three digits $ \Longrightarrow A^3_3 = 3! $
$\\$
So  the  answer  is $ \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} \times 3 \times 
3! $

Without zero: choose two numbers from $\{2,4,6,8\}$ and two numbers from $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$, this gives you $\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}$ combinations of four digits. There are then $4!$ permutations of these digits so the total is $\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot4! = 1440$
With zero: assuming the first digit can't be $0$, you have to deal with the two cases separately, one where the first digit is odd, one where the first digit is even:

First digit odd: choose one number from $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ to be the starting digit. Then choose another number from the remaining four odd digits and two numbers from $\{0,2,4,6,8\}$, and permute these three digits: $5\cdot4\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot3!$
First digit even: choose one number from $\{2,4,6,8\}$ to be the starting digit (the first digit cannot be $0$). Then choose another number from the remaining four even digits (including $0$) and two numbers from $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$, and permute the final three digits: $4\cdot4\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot3!$

So in total there are $5\cdot4\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot3! + 4\cdot4\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot3! = 9\cdot4\cdot\binom{5}{2}\cdot3! = 2160$
Although this answer disagrees with the one quoted by OP by a factor of 3...
